# How to use react-toggle with React redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-redux-form, react-toggle

Is it possible to use [react-toggle](https://github.com/aaronshaf/react-toggle) with Redux form?

react-toggle renders a toggle like so:

```
<Toggle
  icons={false}
  onChange={this.handleToggleChange}
/>
```

Given a redux-form Field component like so:

```
              <Field
                name="email_newsletter"
                id="email_newsletter"
                component="input"
                type="checkbox"
              />
```

How can react-toggle update the value for the redux-form Field?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a custom renderer like this:

```
export const renderToggleInput = (field) => (
  <Toggle checked={field.input.value} onChange={field.input.onChange} icons={false} />
);
```

and set it to the `component` prop of the `Field` component:

```
<Field
    name="email_newsletter"
    id="email_newsletter"
    component={renderToggleInput}
/>
```

**Warning:** according to the [value prop documentation](http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/docs/api/Field.md/#-code-input-value-any-code-), the `value` type need to be defined.

> It will be a boolean for checkboxes, and
>   a string for all other input types. If there is no value in the Redux
>   state for this field, it will default to ''. This is to ensure that
>   the input is controlled. If you require that the value be of another
>   type (e.g. Date or Number), you must provide initialValues to your
>   form with the desired type of this field.

So you need to define also initial value for your checkbox in your redux-form.

You will find more details in the [Redux-Form Field documentation](http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/docs/api/Field.md/#usage)

Comment: thank you.. that errors w `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `checked` of type `string` supplied to `Toggle`, expected `boolean`.`

Comment: I tried changing it to `checked={field.input.value == 'true')} ` given the react-toggle returns a string not a boolean... now the toggle can be set from false to true, but not back from true to false, it gets stuck

Comment: @AnApprentice I think I found your problem, I updated my answer

Comment: sorry, not seeing any change to the idea?

Comment: @AnApprentice, you need to provide `initialValues` to your `redux-form` with `email_newsletter` set to `true` or `false` (just to ensure the boolean type)

Comment: `<Field type="checkbox" name="email_newsletter" id="email_newsletter" component={renderToggleInput} />` is what's needed to add the checkbox per example https://redux-form.com/7.0.3/examples/simple/ thanks @AdrienLacroix